# Why does my javascript not execute when added to the bundler

Tags: asp.net

I have javascript in an external .js file that executes when the page loads. If I include the .js file individually it works file. When I include it in the bundle it doesn't execute. I verified that the script is delivered to the browser by looking at it with Fire Bug. What am I doing wrong?

Script in LoadTime.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
alert("0");
});
```

Working include:

```
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/assets/js/LoadTime.js")"></script>
```

Non-working include:

```
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/AllScript")
```

BundleConfig code:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/AllScript").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
            "~/Scripts/modernizr-*",
            "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
            "~/Scripts/respond.js",
            "~/assets/js/jquery.min.js",
            "~/assets/js/jquery.dropotron.min.js",
            "~/assets/js/skel.min.js",
            "~/assets/js/skel - viewport.min.js",
            "~/assets/js/util.js",
            "~/assets/js/main.js",
            "~/assets/js/LoadTime.js"));
```

Comment: Jquery was included twice. Thank you for pointing it out @greyfox.

Answer (score 1):

You are including jQuery twice.

```
"~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"
```

and

```
"~/assets/js/jquery.min.js",
```

Only include it once.